# Java WebStart in Websphere

Tags: java, xml, java-web-start, jnlp

We are using WebSphere as our servlet container, and when I deploy the war file into the server, typing `http://localhost:9080/jwsProject/launch.jnlp` always returns **DownloadResponse$NotFoundResponse**. We use JNLPServlet to redirect all requests, the exception is thrown by jnlp-serlvet class.

Following is the war file lay-out:

- index.html
- application.jar
- launch.jnlp
- WEB-INF

  - lib
  - web.xml

**The launch.jnlp has:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="$$codebase" href="launch.jnlp"> 

<information> 
    ...
</information>

<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security> 

<resources>
    <j2se version="1.2+"/>
    <jar href="application.jar" version="1.0" main="true" download="eager"/>
    <jar href="WEB-INF/lib/jnlp-servlet.jar"/>
    <jar href="WEB-INF/lib/jnlp.jar"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="test.maintest.java">
    <argument...</argument>
</application-desc>
```

**The web.xml has:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application    2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">

<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JnlpDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.javaws.servlet.JnlpDownloadServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name> logLevel </param-name>
            <param-value> DEBUG </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JnlpDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>*.jnlp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jnlp</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-java-jnlp-file</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <mime-type>application/java-archive</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```